# Time comparison between 'ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent' and 'new T[]'

Tags: c#

I read a very nice [blog](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/) about `ArrayPool<T>` and the benefits of using it for large objects. Of course I wanted to try it immediately! My example is not that fancy as the one shown in the blog though (the author uses `BenchmarkDotNet` tests). However my test fails to show the same result and I am trying to understand the reason behind. Here is what I tried:

```
var _Pool = ArrayPool<int>.Shared;

var sizeToAllocate = 100_000;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
var rentAndRetur = _Pool.Rent(sizeToAllocate);
_Pool.Return(rentAndRetur);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Using 'Rent' + cleared with 'Return':   {sw.Elapsed}");

sw.Reset();

sw.Start();
var allocated = new int[sizeToAllocate];
allocated = null; //make sure 'allocated' is set to null so the GC can collct the allocated memory
GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true); // the size of the array > 85 000 bytes which means the LOH should be used for allocation (param 3 should be correct for LOH Gen)
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Allocated with 'new' + GC collected:    {sw.Elapsed}");
```

Here are the results for different array sizes:

```
// size: 10 000
// Using 'Rent' + cleared with 'Return':   00:00:00.0006801
// Allocated with 'new' + GC collected:    00:00:00.0001328

// size 100 000
// Using 'Rent' + cleared with 'Return':   00:00:00.0006803
// Allocated with 'new' + GC collected:    00:00:00.0001088

// size: 1 000 000
// Using 'Rent' + cleared with 'Return':   00:00:00.0007203
// Allocated with 'new' + GC collected:    00:00:00.0006110
```

As you can see something is terribly wrong here. As the '**Rent N' Return**' operations seem to take almost constant time my best guess is that I don't force the Garbage collection correctly so I can measure the time taken to collect `allocated` array from the heap (I need to include the `GC.Collect()` time taken so it can be a fair fight).
Someone has any idea how to fix this example so it shows the expected result ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot expect Stopwatch to measure performance reliably, especially with sub-milliseconds times like here.

Comment: Try it in a loop e.g. 10000 times, then collect only after the loop finished. And I'm not sure that `.Return` cleares the array. I think it's not. Thus you may not include the GC into the test. But count amount of collections performed. The best suitable way is Benchmark.NET.

Comment: Take some time to understand Benchmark.NET and rewrite your benchmarks to use it. It's a standard tool, while `Stopwatch` is extremely unreliable.